# Has the EU sued any site(s) yet for not complying with their cookie "law"?

Tags: legal, cookie, eu-cookie-law

> EUROPA websites must follow the Commission's guidelines on privacy and data protection and inform users that cookies are not being used to gather information unnecessarily. *[- source](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm#section_2)*

Many people find this EU cookie directive, when implemented, a broken toy law and a waste of time for all parties involved and because of that don't implement it.

4+ years further, have any of the bodies in the EU sued or attempted to sue any site(s) for not displaying a notice that cookies were in use?

It seems the EU got really quiet about it after the firestorm meteor shower of OP resentment hailed down uponith them and I would love to know how far they actually took it.

Comment: I hate the cookie law. It is one thing to make a visible link, but the requirement goes too far. It takes away from UX and I do not feel it really helps at all.

Comment: @closetnoc Yeah I agree totally. Apparently a link is enough, but regardless, crufty oldhead politicians with no concept of technical architectures aren't the ones who should be policing architecture policies. If people want to block their data from flowing into a site they can simply block the cookies + opt-out + notrack + adblock......or just not visit the property. Of course I don't expect crufty oldheads to understand this, which is why im curious how far they have taken their ignorant joyride. So far I have not been able to find any cases where litigations came to light (which is cool :))

Comment: There should be early retirement for the crufty oldhead politicians- it would be worth the money!

Comment: Although end users do appear to be aware of this "warning" popping up on numerous sites, I've not met a non-techy end user that actually knows what it is, what a cookie is or even cares!

Comment: We all hate cookie law. But it's a law.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first fines specifically for cookie law compliance failures have been handed out by the Spanish Data Protection Authority.  They were given to two companies running a number of jewellery websites, one of which was an online store.

[Further Reading](http://privacylawblog.fieldfisher.com/2014/history-in-the-making-the-first-cookie-rule-fines-in-europe)