# Has anyone ever got in legal trouble for not having those horrific "cookie warnings" on their site?

Tags: web-development, legal, cookie, eu-cookie-law

I know about some idiotic EU "law" that made every damn website add the most obnoxious garbage ever: a huge "warning" about how they are "using cookies", which doesn't let you do anything until you "accept" it. I've been forced to use a special browser extension to get rid of that cancer; it was pure torture, as bad as blinking, screaming advertisements.

When I was running websites, I never once implemented this. Anyone who did/does has something wrong in their head as far as I'm concerned. It's a typical example of blindly following any madness just because "it's a law", regardless of whether it makes any sense or not.

I'm now wondering if not having that crap (which pisses off every single visitor) actually has ever resulted in any kind of "legal action", and if so, but who? I would argue that even if this did happen, the savings in goodwill from not subjecting every visitor to that crap would make up for it no matter how big the monetary penalty is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has the EU sued any site(s) yet for not complying with their cookie "law"?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86131/has-the-eu-sued-any-sites-yet-for-not-complying-with-their-cookie-law)